# NullPointerException when traversing through node of hibernate source code using SDG(System dependence graph)

Tags: java, hibernate, static-analysis

I need to analyze the behaviour of hibernate methods. So I wrote a hibernate application and I want to traverse through each and every method in hibernate jar. So I am using system dependence graph API and I am giving hibernate application main class as a input to system dependence graph API.

While traversing  at one point its is giving null pointer exception and execution stop there.

I am not getting where the problem is coming in hibernate source code.

This is the code of my hiberante application main class:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
    SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    ClientProgram cp = new ClientProgram();
     cp.fetchRecordUsingGet(session);
    System.out.println("Object Loaded successfully.....!!");
    session.close();
factory.close();
}
```

code to access system dependence graph :

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, NodeNotFoundException, AnalyzerException {
        SystemDependenceGraph sdg = new SystemDependenceGraph("E:\Hibernate\bin", "E:\Hibernate\bin\str\ClientProgram.class");
        Iterator  iterator = sdg.controlDependenceDFSIterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Node node = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Node type call: "+node.getName().contains("call")+"\n"+"Node calling name: "+node.getCallingName()
                    +"\n"+"Name: "+node.getName()+"\n"+"line number: "+node.getLine()+"\n");
    }

This is last node on my console on running system dependence class:

Node type call: false
Node calling name: null
Name: org/hibernate/loader/custom/sql/SQLQueryReturnProcessor.entitySuffixSeed = org/hibernate/loader/custom/sql/SQLQueryReturnProcessor.entitySuffixSeed + 1
line number: 320
Node type call: true
Node calling name: generateSuffixes
Name: call org/hibernate/loader/BasicLoader.generateSuffixes
line number: -1

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at SDGTest.main(SDGBeginning.java:36)
Please help in this regard.

Comment: please post the relevant code..

Comment: without source code? I didn't know SO had wizards in it.